# Webview2 - URL to Image

Tags: vb.net, webview2

**Background**

I am relatively new to using the Webview2 control instead of the built in Webbrowser one. I have successfully made some javascripts that help me log in and authenticate myself to a particular website. Within a table from this website, there are a bunch of images.

My end goal is to have a datatable on my application that has all of these images displayed. So far I have all of the source URLs for each image but just need to convert them to the actual images themselves.

**How I used to be able to do it using built in Webbrowser Control**

```
Private Async Function GetBitmapFromLink(ByVal ImagePath As String) As Task(Of Image)
    Dim request As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(ImagePath)

    Dim response As System.Net.WebResponse = Await request.GetResponseAsync()
    Dim responseStream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim Img As New Bitmap(responseStream)
    Return Img
End Function
```

**Goal**

I would like to be able to do a similar function using the Webview2 control instead but am having a hard time finding similar functions. For example, there is no `Webview2.WebRequest`. I am guessing that similar functions exist in Webview2 but I am just not able to find them.

My question is: How do I make a similar image download function like the one I have shown for the old built in Webbrowser control?

Comment: The code you have posted has nothing to do with the WebBrowser Control, it's just a method that issues a WebRequest using the URL of a resource. Since you have *all of the source URLs for each image*, you just do the same thing -- It's quite important that you declare a WebResponse object with a `Using` statement (of course this applies to all disposable objects)

Comment: @Jimi The problem is that to run just the above message results in a rejection from the server as the authentication happened prior to this method. This method does not see the authentication at all since it is a brand new request. It has to be done from the same session already initiated. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

WebView2 does not have a mechanism to start a web request. However, it does have `CoreWebView2.WebResourceResponseReceived` which you can use to monitor the responses to web requests made from within the WebView2.

You may be able to `CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync` to inject script to start background web requests via `fetch()` or `new Request()` and then watch for the result of those with `CoreWebView2.WebResourceResponseReceived`. In the `CoreWebView2WebResourceResponseReceivedEventArgs` there is a `Response` property that has a `GetContentAsync()` async method that gives you the response stream.